# Child theme is not inheriting Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme

I have just started to use magento and made a child theme of Blank. I have followed the documentation about making a theme at

[devdocs.magento.com](http://devdocs.magento.com)

And i have activated the theme but the problem is i dont know why require.js or Icons are not loading. I have tried to deploy the static content but no results, do i have to copy them from Parents theme (But shouldn't child theme inherit?)

[image: Console error]

**Folder Structure**

```
app/design/frontend/myVendor/
├── myTheme/
│   ├── etc/
│   │   ├── view.xml //Copy from vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank
│   ├── media/
│   │   ├── preview.jpg
│   ├── web/
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   ├── logo.svg 
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   ├── source
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── js
│   ├── registration.php
│   ├── theme.xml
│   ├── composer.json
```

Also my **registration.php**

```
 <?php
  /**
  * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
  * See COPYING.txt for license details.
  */

 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
   'frontend/myVendor/myTheme',__DIR__);
```

And **theme.xml**

```
 <theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
 <title>myTheme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
 <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme, in case your theme inherits from an existing theme -->
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
    </media>
 </theme>
```

And also a question, does magento looks in vendor for theme? ( i have read that if it doesnt find it in app/design/frontend that it gets it from vendor)

[Issue about this on git with answer](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2577)

If understood it correctly it wouldnt make me select this theme if it didn't

Comment: Can you add folder structure of your theme to this question?

Comment: @DEEPJOSHI added

Comment: In the latest version of Magento 2 you will fid it under `design/frontend/Magento`

Comment: @DEEPJOSHI yeah but i used composer and it isnt inside but from the link i gave this is how its supposed to be (if i understood right)

Comment: Core modules was in `vendor` in Merchant Version.

Comment: there are no layout folder are exist inside theme folder, plz it remove from your theme.

Comment: @Rakesh You are right thanks for noticing that (its in Magento_Theme/layout)

Comment: i have just added answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to just create theme inside `app/design` folder.

**Folder Structure**

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/
├── myTheme/
│   ├── etc/
│   │   ├── view.xml //Copy from vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank
│   ├── media/
│   │   ├── preview.jpg
│   ├── web/
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   ├── logo.svg 
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   ├── source
│   │   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── js
│   ├── registration.php
│   ├── theme.xml
│   ├── composer.json
```

You have to create layout folder its position is inside module folder.

like,
 `Magento_Catalog/layout/*.xml` file

Try using above concepts its working.

Thanks.

Comment: I will try it again without having to copy from Parents theme. Like you suggested. Magento should inherit that from Parent right?

Comment: yes, its get remaining file from paretn blank theme

Comment: How is the folder structure different from the one OP posted?

Comment: How is this a solution? What does the layout of the Magento_Catalog have to do with inheriting things like LESS files?

Answer (score -1):

Copy following folders from it's parent theme to your theme:

`Magento_Theme`
`media`
`web`

For more details on creating Theme in Magento 2:

http://www.chriscrewdson.co.uk/blog/creating-an-magento-2-theme.html

Comment: That did the trick, but shouldnt Child theme inherit that from Parent?

Comment: This did solve my problem and thank you for that but i was trying to do it with inheritance so i selected Rakesh

Comment: Theme fallback will be handled by the xml of that particular module in magento 2.

Comment: Will have to reread documentation once more to get this entirely, but thank you again

Comment: How is this solving the problem? It should inherit from parent without you needing to add the files.